# How to redirect to a Sitecore page with Data from Controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore

I am submitting a form in Sitecore MVC using `Html.Sitecore().FormHandler()`. My requirement upon validation in the action, it should be redirected to another Sitecore page with some of the form data (I am using `Linkmanager` for that). How to achieve the same from a Controller action?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RedirectToRoute()`and pass parameters between actions as below

```
Item item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse("{GUID_OF_ITEM_WHERE_YOU_WANT_TO_REDIRECT}"));
var pathInfo = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, UrlOptions.DefaultOptions);
return RedirectToRoute(MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, new { pathInfo = pathInfo.TrimStart(new char[] { '/' }), param1 = actionParam });
```

It works as standard HTTP GET with URL params appended by *"?"* to your URL, therefore, you can't pass complex models between your actions, only simple types.